# Is there a way to compile x64 program using minGW in my 64 bit PC?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, mingw-w64

Whenever I compile a C program inside my 64 bit computer using minGW. It turns out that the  compiled program is 32 bit by default. Because of the fact that `sizeof(pointer) = 4` rather than `8`.

Is there a way that I can compile x64 bit programs using minGW. Or maybe minGW does not support 64-bit compilation

Comment: Try `-m64` option,

Comment: Then if your compiler says something like "sorry, unimplemented", then your compiler doesn't support that.

Comment: Note that there is an old 32-bit mingw and a newer 32/64 mingw-w64.  I use msys2 with mingw-w64.

Comment: @tadman Mingw _is_ GCC. The Windows port.

Comment: @Lundin What version of GCC is it? The site (which isn't even secure!) makes it very hard to determine that.

Comment: Are you using Mingw32 or Mingw64? There are two versions of it, the original is as far as I know no longer maintained. Even my very old version of Mingw64 from 2014 has 8 byte pointers.

Comment: @tadman I think gcc 10.3 according to this: http://winlibs.com/

Comment: ... also the presence of the mingw-w64 tag on SO, added to this question, kind of gave away that a 64 bit version exists...

Answer (score 1):

You should use MinGW-w64 instead of classic MinGW.
MinGW-w64 supports both Windows 32-bit and 64-bit.
Recent standalone builds of GCC with MinGW-w64 can be downloaded from http://winlibs.com/